# Bash script - making set of subdirectories according to some file names in the directory

Tags: vasp

I have a set of files like this in a directory named 'test':

```
cij_000.POSCAR cij_001.POSCAR cij_002.POSCAR ....... cij_029.POSCAR
```

It has also four other files in the same 'test' directory as:

```
INCAR POSCAR POTCAR KPOINTS
```

What I want is, I want to create subdirectories within the 'test' directory according to the 'cij_xxx.POSCAR' file name (for example, as 'calc-xxx' are the subdirectory names), and then copy/link the other files (except the POSCAR file), and finally copy/link the 'cij_xxx.POSCAR' file to that subdirectory ('calc-xxx') as the name 'POSCAR'.

I tried the following bash script, somehow it is not doing anything (not creating the 'calc' directory and not linking the files thereby).

Could you please suggest me what should I correct, or any revised bash script suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

The bash script I tried (which didn't work unfortunately):

```
#!/bin/bash

for s in $* ; do
    d=${s%%.POSCAR}
    echo -n  $d ": "
mkdir calc-$d
    (   
        cd calc-$d
    ln -s ../INCAR ../KPOINTS ../POTCAR .
    ln -s ../$s POSCAR
    )
done
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A useful way to debug bash scripts is to `echo` each variable as it's set. At least on my system your for loop doesn't actually list all files, and the part where you extract the number `xxx` also does not work.. You could try

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in ./*.POSCAR ; do
    echo $filename
    d=$(echo "$filename" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
    echo -n $d ": \n"
    mkdir -p calc-$d
    cd calc-$d
    ln -sf ../INCAR ../KPOINTS ../POTCAR .
    ln -sf ../$filename POSCAR
    cd ..
done
```

The `mkdir -p` and `ln -f` flags removes errors from directories already existing, and makes `ln` overwrite any previous link.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me what is the role of this part '| grep -o -E '[0-9]+')'?

Comment: It returns the part of $filename that contains one or more (ASCII) digits. The -E flag tells grep to interpret the pattern '[0-9]+' as a regular expression, and the -o flag means only the matching part is printed.

Comment: Thanks. It helps.